# Intermediate Code as a result of OpenMP pragmas

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pthreads, openmp

Is there a way to get my hands on the intermediate source code produced by the OpenMP pragmas?
I would like to see  how each kind of pragmas is translated.

Cheers.

Comment: @Gray, as suggested by you, I have tagged it with C++ and C.

Comment: Are you looking for something more than, or other than, the assembler files that your compiler (optionally) writes ?

Comment: @High Performance Mark, I would be interested only in source-level code?
Assembly is too messy to probe into.

Comment: @takwing - The transformations are done by the compiler, without rewriting the source code. There is nothing to see!

Comment: @everyone, thank you for all your effort.

Comment: @PavanManjunath: `-E` won't resolve `#pragma`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenMp pragmas is part of a C / C++ compiler's implementation. Therefore before using it, you need to ensure that your compiler will support the pragmas ! If they are not supported, then they are ignored, so you may get no errors at compilation, but multi-thread wont work. In any case, as mentioned above, since they are part of the compiler's implementation, the best intermediate result that you can get is a lower level code. OpenMp is language extension + libraries, macros etc opposed to Pthreads that arms you purely with libraries !