# How to convert openmp version of a program to pthreads version?

Tags: pthreads, openmp

Is there any tool or application for converting openmp to pthreads program? Please let me know.

Answer (score 5):

There is [Rose Compiler](http://rosecompiler.org/).

It works, but it is quite complicated to compile it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any and I don't believe that is possible, as there are indefinite possibilities of what is necessary in order to produce a working and scaling parallel program.

As each programming model (as pthreads and OpenMP) has its special features and pitfalls, it is virtually impossible to automate this process.

Use the opportunity to enhance your program while converting it by hand!

Comment: I think that openmp compiler first translates openmp into some threads library such as pthreads. But I am not sure how to get this pthreads version of the program.

Comment: Your question is related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839218/intermediate-code-as-a-result-of-openmp-pragmas It doesn't solve it though...

Comment: @kkp, the closest thing to transformed code that you can get is some pseudocode from the intermediate code tree transformation steps and even then you'd get code that uses the OpenMP support runtime calls and not `pthreads` directly. And those runtimes **are not** simple wrappers over the threading API - see `libgomp` from GCC as a concrete example.